# C# winforms telerik radGridView добавление картинки

Tags: c#, winforms

Как добавить картинку в ячейку radGridView?

Я делаю добавление следующим образом:

```
this.RgvIncome.Rows[index].Cells["View"].Value = (Image)bitmaps[0];
```

Вылетает исключение.

Comment: Покажите ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Добавление как оказалось правильное. Ошибка была в массиве картинок. Отсутствовал указатель на нужный ресурс)